# Redirect to Named Route from RouteConfig or Controller Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following named route in ASP.NET MVC:

```
[Route("build", Name = "Build")]
public ActionResult Build()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have a situation where this app no longer has a Home page, no need for /Home/Index.cshtml. However, I do not want to deleted Index.cshtml nor do I want to move Build.cshtml code to Index.cshtml

I simply want the default route to be my Build route. Unfortunately, having the named Build route, `[Route("build", Name = "Build")]`, which I use places throughout the application, `@Html.RouteLink("GET BUILDING", "Build")` is making it so I can not do a simple redirect from http://www.mywebsite.com to http://www.mywebsite.com/build with either of the following ways:

In my RouteConfig, this does not work, the resource cannot be found when you go to http://wwww.mywebsite.com:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Build", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Also, and this is more surprising, this does not work either, also results in the resource cannot be found when you go to http://wwww.mywebsite.com:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToRoute("Build");
}
```

I comment out my named Route like so:

```
//[Route("build", Name = "Build")]
public ActionResult Build()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then my RouteConfig way above works.

I would prefer to Redirect to the named route in my RouteConfig though it is fine to if I can Redirect to named route from my /home/index Action method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RouteLink` takes the route name, not the route pattern/template, so you can simply change the route pattern to `""` (empty string)

```
[Route("", Name = "Build")]
public ActionResult Build()
{
    return View();
}
```

When a request comes for `yourSiteName.com`, it will be handled by `Build` action method ,because it matches with the route pattern (*nothing after the baseurl*)

All your existing code which uses the route name in the `RouteLink` helper method  will still work as we did not change that.

```
@Html.RouteLink("GET BUILDING", "Build")
```

If you want to have `yourSiteName/Build` to also work, you can add another route with the route pattern "" along with your current route definition.

```
[Route("")]
[Route("build", Name = "Build")]
public ActionResult Build()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now when a request comes for `yourSiteName.com` or `yourSiteName.com/build`, it will be handled by `Build` action method